# One-time download ListView data - Service or Bundle?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-service

I'm developing an app that downloads `ParseObject`'s data from server and populate a `ListView` in `Fragment` with it.

I read about downloading data by `Service` and after it's done (some kind of `listener`?) it would update `Fragment` and be accessible until user leaves the app (which is fine by me).

On the other hand - I can just store it in `Bundle` and retrieve it every time I get back to that `Fragment`, but then I'd need implement `Serializable` which in this case can be cumbersome: [like here](http://www.androidbook.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=4539&ownerUserId=android)

Fragments are held by `DrawerLayout` so it's really irritating now to see loading bar everytime You change to that `Fragment` and I'm looking for a solution to change that to improve UX.

What do You suggest? Which approach would be better in that situation? Maybe there are things that I should be aware of before attempting to use any of these?

Comment: It depends on `ParseObject` structure. Different objects could be differently saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how often the data is changed on the server.

If only daily/weekly the solution must differ compared to if the data is changed every mins/hours.

If the data is kind of static then you can download it only once, and save it to SharedPreferences, or to a seperate local file or DB.

If it changes kinda often, I'd suggest to use bundles or in memory objects, so when the user reenters the app the data should be downloaded again.

Comment: Well, user will not this use more than 5 minutes per session, but will open app like 2,3 times a day. So update every time user enters app would be sufficent.

Comment: Is the dataobject shared between multiple fragments? Or used by one fragment, but you don't want to load every time the user checks that screen?

Comment: Nope, just for one fragment. Exactly what You said: I don't want to load every time user checks that screen :)

Comment: Then I think you should save the Fragment's state, and load it back when user reenters the fragment. Also make sure you don't create a new Fragment every time the user checks that screen, check [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) if not yet familiar with it. This way you'll need to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) with your data object so it can be saved quickly by the system. But most of the time you'll be able to get the saved object from memory, if the fragment's not reloaded.

Comment: Wait, that: `Also make sure you don't create a new Fragment every time the user checks that screen` - how can I do that? I need to check that one!

Comment: Okay, from what I read the solution is to download data on `Activity` holding that fragments and pass it through `newInstance(data_here)`, but to to that (i.e. pass to `Bundle`) I need to implement `Parcelable` which is double-function here: to retain data and pass it to `Fragment`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, Parcelable can be used both ways. Also about Fragment creation; you can retain existing Fragments with the fragmentmanager, or from saved state.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i'd use would be to simply convert the entire list of data to JSON, and then save it in SharedPreferences. This allows for easy reuse of the data when the user goes back to that fragment.

As you aren't saving the data across app close/reopen, a local database is not needed.